# Getting Disk Space Attributes NSFileSystem +attributesOfFileSystem doesn't match info in iOS Settings App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm trying to get the total / used / free space from my iOS app in bytes, using the following code, adapted from various solutions on this website.

```
 - (unsigned long long)totalDiskSpace {

     unsigned long long space = 0;

     NSError *error = nil;

     NSArray<NSString *> *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSDictionary *dict = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:paths.lastObject error:&error];

     if (dict) {

         NSNumber *size = dict[NSFileSystemSize];
         space = size.unsignedLongLongValue;

     }

     return space;

 }

 - (unsigned long long)freeDiskSpace {

     unsigned long long space = 0;

     NSError *error = nil;

     NSArray<NSString *> *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSDictionary *dict = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:paths.lastObject error:&error];

     if (dict) {

         NSNumber *size = dict[NSFileSystemFreeSize];
         space = size.unsignedLongLongValue;

     }

     return space;
}
```

The issue is, when I compare the values to what the use might see in their Settings.app, they're totally off I'm testing on a 256 GB iPhone X, and while the "total" space value is correct, the value for "free" space seems be a lot less than it should be.

On my device, I'm getting a value of `255937040384` (~255GB), but only `175536754688` for Free, which translates to `80400285696` used (~80GB). BUT, in Settings.app, my device shows only 52.4 GB used.

Anyone know why that may be?

Comment: Do you still see this if you use `NSURL`'s `resourceValuesForKeys:` with `NSURLVolumeCapacityKey` and `NSURLVolumeTotalCapacityKey` instead?

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure how that is relevant. Per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlresourcekey?language=objc), NSURLResourceKey only has values for total space, not free or used space. The total space value I get from NSURL is the same I get from NSFileManager, and it is accurate. It is the amount of *free* space I'm looking for which is inaccurate. NSFileManager says that there is ~30GB less space than is actually available, per Settings.app

Comment: That's not true; [per the documentation,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlresourcekey/checking_volume_storage_capacity?language=objc) `NSURLResourceKey` contains three constants to check the amount of free space: `NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityKey`, `NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey`, and `NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityForOpportunisticUsageKey`. If my hunch is correct, the Settings app may be reading one of these as the available space (probably `...ForImportantUsageKey`), rather than the literal amount of physical space on the drive. One way to find out.

Comment: I don't have an iOS device to test on, but when I try this on my Mac, `NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey` gives the amount reported by the Finder and `NSFileManager` gives a few GB less. It's because the OS reports some files as non-essential and can automatically delete those if space is needed for something else, so it factors them into the free space. I'm betting the iOS Settings app is doing the same thing. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I must have missed that key! Thank you! It indeed behaves exactly as you said -- NSFileManager gives slightly less because of Apple "purgeable" space system.

Comment: Great! Since my hunch proved to be correct, I've rewritten it as an answer. If you could mark it as accepted, that'd be great. :-)

Comment: Done. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `NSFileManager`, use `NSURL`'s `resourceValuesForKeys:` method to get your drive's free space. `NSURL` provides three relevant constants here:

- `NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityKey`—the literal free space on your drive, which should be identical to the value returned by `NSFileManager`,
- `NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey`—the literal free space on your drive, plus the size of any "ephemeral" files on the disk which can be automatically deleted if needed to provide room for other things, and:
- `NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityForOpportunisticUsageKey`—the amount of space available for ephemeral files themselves, which in my experience is usually something less than the actual free space.

In your case, `NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey` is probably the value that Settings.app is reporting, since from a user standpoint, that is the amount of space that you have to work with.

Also, as a general rule, if you are using an Apple Objective-C or Swift API that takes a path rather than a URL, it's probably a legacy API. The URL-based APIs are usually more complete and up-to-date, and should be generally preferred over the path-based ones—in this case, the path-based API predating the Important/Opportunistic concept causes it to lack the facilities for reading those values.